# Is there a tool like PySimpleGUI for Perl?

Tags: perl, user-interface, sh

I am looking for a Perl GUI tool that is as simple as [PySimpleGUI](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI). PySimpleGUI claims to be a good choice for things like this:

- add the convenience of a simple GUI onto a CLI Perl script.
- share some cool Perl tools I run from the terminal but give the (internal) users a simple GUI
- share my Perl programs with friends or family (that aren't so comfortable with the CLI)
- run a program in the system tray (potentially)
- looking for a GUI package that is "supported" and is being constantly developed and improved
- good documentation and examples

Those are my requirements and because PySimpleGUI offers all that, I gave it a try for a project. I liked it. That prompted to to try to find something like it for **Perl**.

I'm running perl 5, version 30 on Linux with KDE.

So far I only found:

- saiftynet/GUIDeFATE: GUI Design From A Text Editor https://github.com/saiftynet/GUIDeFATE

I was not able to get the examples to run, and the supplied documentation doesn't meet my requirements. (I will ask about my specific problems with GUIDeFATE in a separate question, but GUIDeFATE is not actively developed like PySimpleGUI.)

I have used [Kdialog](https://github.com/KDE/kdialog) for bash scripts in the past and it is not what I have in mind.

**Is there an equivalent of PySimpleGUI for Perl?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to find anything like `PySimpleGUI` in Perl. I think you need to build the gui based on the full api of the toolkit (and not a simplified version of the api like `PySimpleGUI`). I know that the [Gtk3](https://metacpan.org/pod/Gtk3)
and [Tk](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Tk/Tk.pod) toolkits are actively used. There are also the [Wx](https://metacpan.org/pod/Wx) and [QtCore4](https://metacpan.org/pod/QtCore4) toolkits, but these are less used and not actively maintained in my opinion.

Here is an example in `Gtk3`:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Gtk3 -init;

my $window = Gtk3::Window->new( 'toplevel' );
$window->signal_connect( destroy  => sub { Gtk3->main_quit() } );
my $grid = Gtk3::Grid->new();
$window->add( $grid );
my $label1 = Gtk3::Label->new('Some text on Row 1');
$grid->attach($label1, 0,0,1,1);
my $label2 = Gtk3::Label->new('Enter something on Row 2');
$grid->attach($label2, 0,1,1,1);
my $entry = Gtk3::Entry->new();
$grid->attach($entry, 1,1,1,1);
my $button1 = Gtk3::Button->new('Ok');
$button1->signal_connect('clicked' => sub { say "You entered ", $entry->get_text( ) } );
$grid->attach($button1, 0,2,1,1);
my $button2 = Gtk3::Button->new('Cancel');
$button2->signal_connect('clicked' => sub { $window->destroy() } );
$grid->attach($button2, 1,2,1,1);
$window->set_position('center_always');
$window->show_all();
Gtk3->main();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is Håkon's example using [Tk](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Tk/Tk.pod)

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;
my $text= '';
my $window = tkinit();
$window->Label(-text =>'Some text on Row 1')->grid();
$window->Label(-text=>'Enter something on Row 2',
           )->grid(
    $window->Entry(-textvariable=> \$text)
);
$window->Button(-text=>'Ok',
                -command=>sub{say "You entered $text"},
            )->grid(
    $window->Button(-text=>'Cancel',-command=>sub{Tk::exit})
);
$window->withdraw;
$window->Popup;
MainLoop;
```